# How can I create a list of records groupedby index in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a CSV of records:

```
name,credits,email
bob,,test1@foo.com
bob,6.0,test@foo.com
bill,3.0,something_else@a.com
bill,4.0,something@a.com
tammy,5.0,hello@gmail.org
```

where `name` is the index. Because there are multiple records with the same name, I'd like to roll the entire row (minus the name) into a list to create JSON of the form:

```
{
  "bob": [
      { "credits": null, "email": "test1@foo.com"},
      { "credits": 6.0, "email": "test@foo.com" }
  ], 
  // ...
}
```

My current solution is a bit kludgey as it seems to use pandas only as a tool for reading CSV, but nonetheless it generates my expected JSONish output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

def read_data():
    s = """name,credits,email
bob,,test1@foo.com
bob,6.0,test@foo.com
bill,3.0,something_else@a.com
bill,4.0,something@a.com
tammy,5.0,hello@gmail.org
"""

    data = io.StringIO(s)
    return pd.read_csv(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = read_data()
    columns = df.columns
    index_name = "name"
    print(df.head())

    records = defaultdict(list)

    name_index = list(columns.values).index(index_name)
    columns_without_index = [column for i, column in enumerate(columns) if i != name_index]

    for record in df.values:
        name = record[name_index]
        record_without_index = [field for i, field in enumerate(record) if i != name_index]
        remaining_record = {k: v for k, v in zip(columns_without_index, record_without_index)}
        records[name].append(remaining_record)
    pprint(dict(records))
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in native pandas (and numpy)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
cols = df.columns.drop('name').tolist()
```

or as recommended by @jezrael:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['name'])
```

and then:

```
s = df.groupby('name')[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_json()
```

let's print it nicely:

```
In [45]: print(json.dumps(json.loads(s), indent=2))
{
  "bill": [
    {
      "credits": 3.0,
      "email": "something_else@a.com"
    },
    {
      "credits": 4.0,
      "email": "something@a.com"
    }
  ],
  "bob": [
    {
      "credits": null,
      "email": "test1@foo.com"
    },
    {
      "credits": 6.0,
      "email": "test@foo.com"
    }
  ],
  "tammy": [
    {
      "credits": 5.0,
      "email": "hello@gmail.org"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Pretty much! If I didn't need to explicitly list the columns following the `groupby`, that would be great, but I think that's trivial.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: and better `cols = df.columns.difference(['name'])`